# Unexpeceted SMTP response in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, smtp

I am receiving strange response in ajax of smtp. I am using following code for smtp.

```
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            $response = array();
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
            $mail->Host = "mail.example.com";
            $mail->Port = 25;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = "Y**********s@Example.com";
            $mail->Password = "Your Password";
            $mail->setFrom($to, $name);
            $mail->addAddress('O**********l@example.com', 'Owner Name');
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $message =  '<div  style="background:#F5F5F5; padding:10px;">
                            <p>'.$message.'</p><br />
                            <div>Name : '.$name.'</div><br />
                            <div>Phone : '.$phone.'</div><br />
                        </div>';
            $mail->msgHTML($message);
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        ); 
        if (!$mail->send()){
            // For Debugging
            //return "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            $response['error'] = 'Something not right. Please check your details.';
        }else{
            $response['success'] = 'Your email has been sent successfully.';
        }
        echo json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Above code is giving me following response when i call that page through ajax.

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO i******9.com
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO i******9.com
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: bm8tcmVwbHlAaWVpMjAwOS5jb20=
CLIENT -> SERVER: R29vZ2xlMDAxIQ==
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:<i******9@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:<no-reply@i******9.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA
CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Thu, 9 Mar 2017 05:53:58 +0000
CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Contact Us Form <no-reply@i******9.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: From: Ai******9z <ii******9o@gmail.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject: Bug
CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: <e40a0335e2698ee9e28de514c2eb325a@i******9.com>
CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.22 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
CLIENT -> SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
CLIENT -> SERVER: boundary="b1_e40a0335e2698ee9e28de514c2eb325a"
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e40a0335e2698ee9e28de514c2eb325a
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: This is a plain-text message body
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e40a0335e2698ee9e28de514c2eb325a
CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: <div style="background:#F5F5F5; padding:10px;">
CLIENT -> SERVER: <p>This is for form testing</p><br />
CLIENT -> SERVER: <div>Name : Ai******9z</div><br />
CLIENT -> SERVER: <div>Phone : 123456789</div><br />
CLIENT -> SERVER: </div>
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: --b1_e40a0335e2698ee9e28de514c2eb325a--
CLIENT -> SERVER:
CLIENT -> SERVER: .
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
{ "success": "Your email has been sent successfully." }
```

Can someone please guide me what is this issue that i can fix it. I would like to appreciate if someone guide me about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

please remove this code and check

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

Comment: You can see that message at the end `{ "success": "Your email has been sent successfully." }` so i think it means there is not error inside SMTP

Comment: its print your debug output

Comment: This is correct. Removing the debug out fixed this for me.